# How to use AndroidViewModel in module

Tags: android, android-room, viewmodel, android-context

I created a module (id 'com.android.library') and it contains a room db. I want to handle inserting and deleting data in viewModel as below;

```
class LanguageViewModel(
application: Application
```

) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

```
private val languageDao = LanguageDatabase.getDatabase(
    application.applicationContext
).languageDao()

private val repository: LanguageRepository = LanguageRepository(languageDao)
val allSelectedLanguages = repository.getAllLanguage

fun insertLanguage(languageModel: LanguageModel) =
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insertLanguage(languageModel)
    }

fun deleteLanguage(languageId: Int) =
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.deleteLanguage(languageId)
    }

}
```

However it crashes,

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class
> com.keyboard.data.room.LanguageViewModel at
> androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:275)

I created a viewModelProvider

```
class LanguageViewModelProvider(
val app: Application,
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return LanguageViewModel(app) as T
}
}
```

but I cannot initialize LanguageViewModelProvider because I can't input application parameter in module.

If I use it in app (id 'com.android.application') it runs perfect.

What can I do?

Comment: Why do you need a `viewModel` in a module? A module is a library, in other words. [Learn about ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: Viewmodels are dedicated companions of activity or fragment, you can not put them into some module, by doing so you are reducing their behavior to mere `UseCase` class or some sort of middle layer classes.